# How to create a nested select with ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I want to set a default value to  `pcate` and `ccate.id` ,how or what should i fix?

My **HTML** is here,

```
<select 
    ng-model="pcate" 
    ng-required="true" 
    ng-change="show(pcate)" 
    ng-options=" pcate.name for pcate in cate">
</select>

<select 
    ng-model="ccate.id" 
    ng-required="true" 
    ng-change="shows(ccate.id)" 
    ng-options="ccate.id as ccate.name for ccate in pcate.son">
</select>
```

My **JSON Structure** is as follows.

```
$scope.cate = [
  {
    "son": [
      {
        "parent_id": 100,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 101,
        "name": "food1"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 100,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 102,
        "name": "food2"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 100,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 103,
        "name": "food3"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 100,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 104,
        "name": "food4"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 100,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 105,
        "name": "food5"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 100,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 106,
        "name": "food6"
      }
    ],
    "parent_id": null,
    "cate_line": "",
    "id": 100,
    "name": "food"
  },
  {
    "son": [
      {
        "parent_id": 200,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 201,
        "name": "flower1"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 200,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 202,
        "name": "flower2"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 200,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 203,
        "name": "flower3"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 200,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 204,
        "name": "flower4"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 200,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 205,
        "name": "flower5"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 200,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 206,
        "name": "flower6"
      }
    ],
    "parent_id": null,
    "cate_line": "",
    "id": 200,
    "name": "flower"
  },
  {
    "son": [
      {
        "parent_id": 300,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 301,
        "name": "service1"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 300,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 302,
        "name": "service2"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 300,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 303,
        "name": "service3"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 300,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 304,
        "name": "service4"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 300,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 305,
        "name": "service5"
      },
      {
        "parent_id": 300,
        "cate_line": "",
        "id": 399,
        "name": "service6"
      }
    ],
    "parent_id": null,
    "cate_line": "",
    "id": 300,
    "name": "service"
  }
]
```

Comment: All the possible expressions of ``ng-options`` can be found in the official documentation of Angular.js: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

You can use somthing like this..

```
   <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.Text for item in      items"></select>
```

Regards
Jasbeer Singh